# WPF ComboBox get displayed text

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, itemtemplate

I'm having a problem with my combo box and trying to get the text that is displayed in the box. I have the ItemsSource bound to a SqlDataReader, and I'm trying to populate another combo box based on what item is selected in the first combo box.

In the first combobox's selection changed event, I'm running a query based on what's selected in that box. However, I can't get that text for the life of me. Everything I've tried always returns "System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal". Even when I try "comboBox.Text", it returns that also despite it not being displayed. Did I do the binding wrong? Or is something wrong with my item template for the combo box?

Here's the relevant code:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbTables"  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=lstTables, Path=ItemsSource}" 
                              SelectionChanged="cbTables_SelectionChanged" >
                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Label Content="{Binding Path=TABLE_NAME}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ComboBox>
```

Tell me if I need to post anything else. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your xaml code. DataRecordInternal is correct item type for sql collection. If you want clr object - bind control to list of clr objects. But if you want just string - you can try this solution:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbTables" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=lstTables, Path=ItemsSource}" 
DisplayMemberPath="TABLE_NAME" SelectedValuePath="TABLE_NAME" SelectionChanged="cbTables_SelectionChanged" />


private void cbTables_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var str = cbTables.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! DisplayMemberPath="TABLE_NAME" SelectedValuePath="TABLE_NAME" was what I needed. I had a feeling it was something simple I was overlooking.